# Restrict Payment Types by Admin Role or Customer group or rather by store?

Tags: payment-methods, ce-1.9.1.0, permissions, user-roles

I am trying to create a salesrep system for a customers store.
These salesreps have limited backend access and can create and edit customers and create orders for their customers as well as viewing their customers orders.

I now have the following issue:

Salesreps should be allowed different payment types than regular store users, but from the roles permissions I can't seem to allow this per role, nor per customer group (the samesrep creates an order on the customers behalf).

So I was wondering what is the best way to do this? Extend the payment type modules to be allowed by store view and use a 2nd store for the salesreps and allow / disallow the specific payment modules per store view, or write a module that checks for roles or customer groups before displaying the payment types?

/edit: Or maybe use Shoppingcart Rules, but I'm not sure these work when creating orders from the backend?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tecjam,

Hi guess that your issue has been solved by  Magento Event Observer.

For Study:

1. [magentocommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method)
2. [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-magento-observers--cms-21031)

Fire an Observer on `payment_method_is_active` event.

Basic of   `Admin Role or Customer group or store`,you can prevent to `show Payment at checkout`.

### Module config.xml code:

```
<global>
    <events>
    <payment_method_is_active>
        <observers>
            <paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>zerosubtotalpaymentmethod/observer</class>
            <method>filterpaymentmethod</method>
            </paymentfilter_payment_method_is_active>
        </observers>
    </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</global>
```

### Observer code is

```
<?php
class Bh_ZeroSubtotalpaymentmethod_Model_Observer {

    public function filterpaymentmethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {

         //currentstore is  Admin
            /* Current Admin User */
            $admin_user_session = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
            $adminuserId = $admin_user_session->getUser()->getUserId();
             if ($adminuserId):  //check if the admin is logged in
                /*
                $role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($adminuserId)->getRole()->getData();
            $role_name = $role_data['role_name'];
                */
             endif

        }else{
        // 
        }



        /* call get payment method */
        $method = $observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance();

        if($method->getCode()=='paypal_standard')
        {   $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if(Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($quote->getGrandTotal())<=0){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
            return;
        }
        if($method->getCode()=='free'){
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            if(Mage::app()->getStore()->roundPrice($quote->getGrandTotal())>0){
            $result = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();   
            $result->isAvailable = false;
            return;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks again Amit, you've helped me for the 2nd time in as many days =)

Comment: wait is give more details....

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this extension. It allows you to set payment methods to only be used in the backend http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-payments.html

The code is available on github (https://github.com/getsquare/Magento-Admin-Payments)

The event that you would want to observe is **payment_method_is_active**.

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                ...
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

In you observer

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$paymentMethod = $event->getMethodInstance();

$result = $observer->getResult();
$result->isAvailable = true;
```

You can do checks agains the payment method code etc `$paymentMethod->getCode()`

`$result->isAvailable = true;` will allow the payment method to be used

Comment: This looks like a great alternative. I'll check it out. Thanks.